# Logic Error inside my code

Tags: java, object

I seem to have a logic error within my code. This is because my first Fan Object (FanOne) should display the following output: Speed: 2, Radius: 10.0, Color: yellow.

Instead it has shows Speed: 1

I would think there is a something wrong with my setSpeed() method .. but to me it seems like everything should work out as intended. Please advise, thank you.

```
public class TestFan {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

 Fan FanOne = new Fan();

 FanOne.fanOn();
 FanOne.setColor("yellow");
 FanOne.setCustomSpeed("MEDIUM");
 FanOne.setCustomRadius(10); 

 System.out.println(FanOne.toString());

System.out.println();

Fan FanTwo = new Fan();

FanTwo.fanOff();
FanTwo.setCustomRadius(5);
FanTwo.setColor("blue");

System.out.println(FanTwo.toString());

 }
}

public class Fan {
 // Declare constant data fields 
 final int SLOW = 1;
 final int MEDIUM = 2;
 final int FAST = 3;

 private int speed;
 private boolean on; 
 private double radius;
 private String color; 

 // Construct a default fan 
 public Fan() {
  speed = SLOW;
  on = false;
  radius = 5;
  color = new String("Blue");
 }

 // Set fan off
 public boolean fanOff() {
  on = false;
  return on;
 }

 // Set fan on
 public boolean fanOn() {
  on = true;
  return on;
 }

 public double getRadius() {
  return radius;
 }

 // Set custom radius 
 public void setCustomRadius(double rad) {
  radius = rad;
 }

 public int getSpeed() {
  return speed;
 }

 // Set custom speed
 public String setCustomSpeed(String speed) {
  if (speed.equals("SLOW")) {
   this.speed = SLOW;  
 } else if (speed.equals("MEDIUM")) {
   this.speed = MEDIUM; 
 } else if (speed.equals("FAST")) {
   this.speed = FAST;
 }
return speed;
}

public String getColor() {
 return color;
}

public void setColor(String colorName) {
 color = colorName;
}

public String toString() {
 if (on == true) {
  return ("Speed: " + speed + ", " + "Radius: " + radius + ", " + "Color: " + color);
 } else {
  return ("Color: " + color + ", " + "Radius: " + radius + ", Alert: " + "The fan is  off!");
 }

 }

}
```

Comment: Y Daniel Liang's Intro to Java textbook assignment. I recognize this problem having used his book to teach for many years!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your setter method for `speed`, `setCustomSpeed`, you are only changing the local `String` variable `speed`, not the instance variable `speed`.  It remains unchanged at `SLOW`, or `1`.

Use `this` to qualify that you mean the instance variable, e.g.

```
this.speed = SLOW;
```

It's an `int` so there is no need to convert your constant to a `String` here.  You can change the other assignment statements accordingly, and you can return `this.speed` also.

Comment: I changed my code to reflect the paradigm you had discussed. The only thing is that I kept on getting an error on "return this.speed". I changed it to return speed which produced the correct output. I am not entirely sure on why that worked. I will def read up on variable scope and shadowing though ;)

Comment: The return type you have is currently `String`, and `speed` is a `String`, so that worked.  You could also return `this.speed`, and change the return type of the method to `int`, and that would work also, depending on what you do want returned - the new stored value or the original `String` input.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is called shadowing.  Your code here:

```
// Set custom speed
 public int setCustomSpeed(String speed) {
  if (speed.equals("SLOW")) {
   speed = String.valueOf(SLOW);  
 } else if (speed.equals("MEDIUM")) {
   speed = String.valueOf(MEDIUM); 
 } else if (speed.equals("FAST")) {
   speed = String.valueOf(FAST);
 }
return speed;
}
```

is setting the local variable speed equal to 2, leaving the Fan class variable speed equal to whatever it was before (the constructor sets it to 1).  Because of this, we need to distinguish the speed variable for the object, using this.speed.  This indicates which variable to use.

```
// Set custom speed
 public String setCustomSpeed(String speed) {
  if (speed.equals("SLOW")) {
   this.speed = String.valueOf(SLOW);  
 } else if (speed.equals("MEDIUM")) {
   this.speed = String.valueOf(MEDIUM); 
 } else if (speed.equals("FAST")) {
   this.speed = String.valueOf(FAST);
 }
return this.speed;
}
```

To avoid this in the future, you should consider using differently named variables, and read up and understand variable scope and shadowing.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the constant field names were defined in the assignment; it wasn't the OPs choosing.

Comment: @hfontanez yes, but the OP won't always be doing homework assignments and will eventually be developing code on their own, in which case it would be good to know

Comment: true that... As a suggestion, I would use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals`

Comment: I changed my code to reflect the paradigm you had discussed. The only thing is that I kept on getting an error on "return this.speed". I changed it to return speed which produced the correct output. I am not entirely sure on why that worked. I will def read up on variable scope and shadowing though ;)

Comment: The error is because this.speed is an interactive and the return type of the method is string